# How to place fields in the form to be of same height and width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place fields in a form one after another (on new lines) to be of same height and width.

Below is the code snippet:

```css
    label {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 120px;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }

    label > span {
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
    }

    input {
         min-width: 169px;
         min-height: 41px;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* or `border-box` */
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
    <label>
          <span>email</span>
          <input type="email"/>
    </label>
    <label>
          <span>Date</span>
          <input type="date"/>
    </label>
```

The above will create input fields one after another on a new line.

However, both of them are of different width. When I change the `box-sizing` to `content-box` for input element, both the input elements are of same width but the increased height is undesirable.

I want the input elements to be of equal width and height.

Could someone help me with this? Also the fields can be dynamically added (meaning more input elements).

Is there a way to let the styling be added to all elements and not change it individually in future. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `min-width` and `min-height` for input boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below updated code:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
label > span {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
input {
  width: 169px;
  height: 24px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* or `border-box` */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <span>email</span>
    <input type="email" />
</label>
<label>
    <span>Date</span>
    <input type="date" />
</label>
```